# Trying to put a player name with apostrophe in href

Tags: mysql, hyperlink, apostrophe

My problem is the next, im having troubles with some names. My application is getting out from database all the names of a team and then i put them in a link (A href) to pass by GET the player name and then charge the stadistics. The code is the next:

```
$sele_t5 = "SELECT * FROM PLAYERS WHERE nom_team='$team' ORDER BY totalpoints DESC LIMIT 5;";
$sele_t5 = mysql_query( $sele_t5, $link );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sele_t5 ) )
                {
                    echo "<TR>";
                    echo "<TD ALIGN='CENTER'><A HREF='?player={$row['nombre']}'>".$row['nombre']."</A></TD>";
}
```

well this is working perfect with all the players except with names with apostrophe, for example:

Jo. O'Brien when i press the link (which show me the full name correct) i got Jo. O in adress bar, is like the apostrophe is cutting the action. Happens the same when i send some name with apostrophe by post, so i would appreciate any solve for this problem.

thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo "<TD ALIGN='CENTER'><A HREF='?player={$row['nombre']}'>"
```

to

```
echo "<TD ALIGN='CENTER'><A HREF='?player=" . urlencode($row['nombre']) . "'>"
```

However, you should really read about MySQL-Injections and Cross-Site-Scripting or you *will* run into big security issues.